# Perform an action for each element of a stream and for any element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to be able to do this:

```
Arrays.stream(args)
  .map(arg -> new File(arg))
  .filter(file -> !file.isFile())
  .forEach(
    file -> System.out.println(String.format("File %s does not exist", file))
  ).forAny(() -> System.exit(1));
```

but since `forEach` returns `void` I have the following code:

```
Stream<File> notExistingFiles = Arrays.stream(args)
  .map(arg -> new File(arg))
  .filter(file -> !file.isFile());
notExistingFiles.forEach(
  file -> System.out.println(String.format("File %s does not exist", file))
);
notExistingFiles.findAny().ifPresent(a -> System.exit(1));
```

Any suggestions how this can be improved?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code won’t work as you can’t process a Stream twice. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709386/2711488) doesn’t work, as `peek` does *not* process every item.

There is, however, no reason to complicate the code by trying to bail everything into Stream actions. Just collect into a collection:

```
Set<File> notExistingFiles = Arrays.stream(args)
    .map(File::new).filter(file -> !file.isFile()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

if(!notExistingFiles.isEmpty()) {
    notExistingFiles.forEach(file -> System.out.printf("File %s does not exist%n", file));
    System.exit(1);
}
```

This code is much easier to understand to the reader.